# How do I test my Firebase V2 Scheduled Functions written in Python using Firebase Shell?

Tags: python, firebase, google-cloud-functions, scheduled-tasks

I created a simple scheduled function to test the shell.

```
  @scheduler_fn.on_schedule(schedule='1 * * * *')
  def logSomething(event: scheduler_fn.ScheduledEvent) -> None:
     print("Reached")
```

I ran:

`% firebase emulators:start`

`% firebase functions:shell`

`firebase > logSomething()`

My output is:
`'Successfully invoked function.'`
and nothing printed.

Pubsub is running:
`i  functions: Connected to running pubsub emulator at 127.0.0.1:8085, calls to this service will affect the emulator`

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? Running into the same issue.